# could not detect network Error

Tags: solidity, hardhat, error, network, hardhat-deploy

I have deployed my contract in vs code with hardhat same as the https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft/
but I got network error like bellow :
[image]

How can i solve this error ??

Comment: Can you share your code and the error message as text?

Comment: Have you defined API_URL in .env?